# How to redirect all my subdomains to https from http

Tags: .htaccess

So i have this code in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.no
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.no/ [R,L]
```

But when i enter a subdomain like (m.mydomain.no) it does not redirect to https, how can i fix this? Thank you

Comment: Most likely your dynamic configuration file does not get applied. Various possible reasons for that: such files might not be enabled in the http server configuration, it might be located at the wrong location or not be readable for the http server process, it might use a module that is not loaded into the http server. Either way: check your http servers error log file. That should _always_ be the first thing you do.

Answer (score 0):

Check this rules, second for http subdomains (non www):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.no
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.no/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```